# android - DownloadTask - how to put source code in dialog box

Tags: java, android

i have following code i put it on click i would like to put urlAll (source code) in AlertDialog

```
        String urlAll="localhost/admin";
        new DownloadTask().execute(urlAll);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(PrintDemo.this).setTitle("Message").setMessage(urlAll).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
```

at the movement i am getting following message

### Result of above code (but i want source code) i am using DownloadTask

localhost/admin

### here is downloadtask funtion

```
 private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         HttpResponse response = null;
         HttpGet httpGet = null;
         HttpClient mHttpClient = null;
         String s = "";

         try {
             if(mHttpClient == null){
                 mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             }


             httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);


             response = mHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
             s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");


         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } 
         return s;
     }
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your expected result? Please give an Example (What is "Result of above code" and what is that "source code" that you are expecting).

Further more, please consider to use onPostExcute to show your dialog. It will be better.

Comment: i already using onpostexcute down for showing dialog

Comment: i want to change the url and display the source of that..... the result of above code is "http://localhost/admin" and i am expecting something like dis <html><body> Thanks for Visiting </body></html> from the url localhost/admin

Comment: @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result){

Comment: i am using onPostExecute for webview url source code...

Comment: execute(urlAll) <-- here is your using.

.setMessage(urlAll) <-- here, you show the "URL" again. Please fix this.

What should be in the message is the result from onPostExcute.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam how to call protected void 

-----onPostExecute(String result){ ---- in ClickEvent

Comment: i mean result inside ClickEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer for your question, I will post it here.

I create a gist for you.

https://gist.github.com/eneim/59df18b4f92065e7d409

Please comment in the gist (create a github account if you don't have one). We should not continue to discuss here :)

Please provide more about your "ClickEvent". But basically, the flow should be like that.